# How to create & configure a (mix & match) framework as module?

Tags: ios, objective-c, configuration, module, xcode6

I've read the "Using Swift with Cocoa & Objective-C" a few times, and I've tried every possible combination of project type (framework, static lib & Swift first, Obj-C first, the lot) but I simply can not get modules to work. I've spent more than 2 hours on this, and it shouldn't be that difficult. Chosing a module name and setting Defines Module to 'yes' doesn't do it.

My goal: to create a module that makes the Apple System Logging service available in Swift code. I've got an objective-c wrapper library lying around that I thought I'd make available as a module to import into my Swift framework, but so far the only luck I've had is it exposing only one of the many classes publically in Swift code. The rest simply aren't available. It's also exposed the 'asl.h' C functions, which is cool, but I have no idea how that happened. I tried creating several sparce frameworks/static libs with the sole goal of making 'asl.h' functions available in Swift. If someone knows how to do that (for any C headers that are part of iOS) without the need to create an Objective-C framework as a module to import into Swift, I'd love to hear about it. Or even just as a framework to make any c headers available in Swift that would be awesome.

So! I create a workspace with an app project in it, and then I create a framework project at the same root level in the workspace as the app project. On the framwork target I set the Product Module Name and Defines Module to 'Yes'. I update my My App's Scheme build target to include the framwork above the app target. I ensure the Link Binary With Libraries build phase contains the framework. Build the app target after adding an 'import MyFramework' line in a Swift file and boom. Failure.

Obviously I've tried clean builds, deleting Derived Data for all projects, hopping one leg and trashing everything and starting again. Someone, anyone, had success with modules yet?

Comment: I am running into the same problem.  Do you find a solution yet?